# Get record Count and retrieve some values from other tables In result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Please consider this scenario:

I have three table like this : My main table that contains details data :

```
 ID     CityCode          Switch1      Switch2      Price          Desc
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1        202               10            1         2342        Some Desc     
 2        202               10            1          12         Some Desc
 3        202               12            1          22         Some Desc
 4        203               10            1          46         Some Desc
 5        203               12            1          23         Some Desc
 6        203               12            1          12         Some Desc
 7        205               14            1         6758        Some Desc
```

`ID` is `Identity` coulmn and is `Primary Key`.

Another table is `CityTypes`:

```
CityCode            CityName             CityType
--------------------------------------------------
  202                City 1                 1
  203                City 2                 2
  204                City 3                 1
  205                City 4                 1
```

and third table is `TotalCount` :this table show Total count record should insert for a specific good in specific City.

```
 Switch1      Switch2       Name           CityType       TotalCount
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
 10            1           Good 1              1             10
 10            1           Good 1              2             5
 10            1           Good 1              3             3
 11            1           Good 2              1             12
 11            1           Good 2              2             8
 11            1           Good 2              3             5
 12            1           Good 3              1             10
 12            1           Good 3              2             5
 12            1           Good 3              3             3
 13            1           Good 4              1             10
 13            1           Good 4              2             5
 13            1           Good 4              3             3
 14            1           Good 5              1             10
 14            1           Good 5              2             5
 14            1           Good 5              3             3
```

`Switch1`+`Switch2`+`CityType` are primary key

I want to write a query that return this result:

```
CityName      GoodName      InsertedCount     TotalCount    InsertedCount-TotalCount
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  City 1      Good 1              2              10                   -8
```

I don't know How I can relate this tables for this query. I wrote this Query:

```
SELECT CityCode,Switch2,Switch1,COUNT(ID)
FROM   tblMain
GROUP BY  CityCode,Switch2,Switch1
ORDER BY CityCode,Switch2,Switch1
```

but I don't know How I can relate this to others tables

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    ct.Cityname,total.name,COUNT(total.*) as insertedcount,sum(total.totalcount) as totalcount, 
    COUNT(total.*)-sum(total.totalcount) as diff
FROM   
    tblMain as main inner join citytypes as ct on main.citycode=ct.citycode
    inner join totalcount as total on ct.citytype=total.citytype
    and main.switch1=total.switch1 and main.switch2=total.switch2 
GROUP BY  ct.Cityname,total.name
ORDER BY ct.Cityname,total.name
```

Comment: I thinks `SUM` should not use in this query.`sum(total.totalcount)` will sum every rows in `TotalCount` table. value in `TotalCount` table for specific `Switch1` and `Switch2` and `CityCode` sould directly place in result set without aggregation

Comment: Sorry  I EDIT my question. In first table `ID` is primary key

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

select ct.cityname, tc.GoodName,COUNT(*) as InsertedCount,sum(tc.totalcount) as TotalCount, 
    COUNT(*)-sum(tc.totalcount) as 'InsertedCount-TotalCount'
FROM tblmain tm
left join CityTypes ct on  ct.citycode = tm.citycode 
left join totalcount tc on tc.citytype = ct.citytype and tm.switch1=tc.switch1 and tm.switch2=tc.switch2
group by ct.cityname, tc.GoodName

Comment: I thinks `SUM` should not use in this query.`sum(total.totalcount)` will sum every rows in `TotalCount` table. value in `TotalCount` table for specific `Switch1` and `Switch2` and `CityCode` sould directly place in result set without aggregation